# I need to create a spark dataframe from a nested json file in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a Json file that looks like this

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "1": "NpProgressBarTag",
      "2": "userPath",
      "3": "screen",
      "4": 6,
      "12": 9,
      "13": "buttonName",
      "16": 0,
      "17": 10,
      "18": 5,
      "19": 6,
      "20": 1,
      "35": 1,
      "36": 1,
      "37": 4,
      "38": 0,
      "39": "npChannelGuid",
      "40": "npShowGuid",
      "41": "npCategoryGuid",
      "42": "npEpisodeGuid",
      "43": "npAodEpisodeGuid",
      "44": "npVodEpisodeGuid",
      "45": "npLiveEventGuid",
      "46": "npTeamGuid",
      "47": "npLeagueGuid",
      "48": "npStatus",
      "50": 0,
      "52": "gupId",
      "54": "deviceID",
      "55": 1,
      "56": 0,
      "57": "uiVersion",
      "58": 1,
      "59": "deviceOS",
      "60": 1,
      "61": 0,
      "62": "channelLineupID",
      "63": 2,
      "64": "userProfile",
      "65": "sessionId",
      "66": "hitId",
      "67": "actionTime",
      "68": "seekTo",
      "69": "seekFrom",
      "70": "currentPosition"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to create a dataframe using

```
val path = "some/path/to/jsonFile.json"
val df = sqlContext.read.json(path)
df.show()
```

when I run this I get

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]
```

How do we create a df based on contents of "tags" key? all I need is, pull data out of "tags" and apply case class like this

```
case class ProgLang (id: String, type: String )
```

I need to convert this json data into dataframe with Two Column names .toDF(id, Type)
Can anyone shed some light on this error?

Comment: Well the first problem is that you are attempting to read a _multi-line_ **JSON**, and as the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) explain, you need to set the `option(key = "multiLine", value = "true")` when reading the **JSON**. However, the second problem is that this **JSON** will create nested fields for every _"id"_... which is not what you want and seems hard to work with. Do you have control over the **JSON** generation? I would 1. make the **JSON** one line and without spaces. 2. Change the structure to `{ "id": "0", "type": "NpProgressBarTag" }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No, I don't have control over Json Generation. Do you have any idea how to convert  this file into CSV file and then load as dataframe with respect to columns(id, Type).

Comment: Use a JSON parsing library to convert it into a suitable format. Then you can use spark to read those files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may modify the JSON using [**Circe**](https://circe.github.io/circe/).

Given that your values are sometimes *Strings* and other times *Numbers*, this was quite complex.

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._

val json = """ ... """ // your JSON here.
val doc = parse(json).right.get
val mappedDoc = doc.hcursor.downField("tags").withFocus { array =>
  array.mapArray { jsons =>
    jsons.map { json =>
      json.mapObject { o =>
        o.mapValues { v =>
          // Cast numbers to strings.
          if (v.isString) v else Json.fromString(v.asNumber.get.toString)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

final case class ProgLang(id: String, `type`: String )
final case class Tags(tags: List[Map[String, String]])
implicit val TagsDecoder: Decoder[Tags] = deriveDecoder

val tags = mappedDoc.top.get.as[Tags]
val data = for {
  tag <- res29.tags
  (id, _type) <- tag
} yield ProgLang(id, _type)
```

Now you have a List of `ProgLang` you may create a `DataFrame` directly from it, save it as a file with each **JSON** per line, save it as a **CSV** file, etc...
If the file is very big, you may use [**fs2**](https://fs2.io/) to stream it while transforming, it [*integrates*](https://github.com/circe/circe-fs2) nicely with **Circe**.

---

***DISCLAIMER:** I am far from being a "pro" with Circe, this seems over-complicated for doing something which seems like a "simple-task", probably there is a better / cleaner way of doing it (maybe using Optics?), but hey! it works! - anyways, if anyone knows a better way to solve this feel free to edit the question or provide yours*.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am getting following error when I am trying to install circle dependencies.

...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: io.circe#circe-parser_2.10;0.10.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  io.circe:circe-parser_2.10:0.10.0 
[warn]  +- tag_decode:tag_decode_2.10:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.circe#circe-parser_2.10;0.10.0: not found
        
...

Comment: @R7777777 you are trying to use **Circe** version `0.10.0` with **Scala** `2.10` which **Circe** [dropped support since `0.9.3`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-parser), you can either use **Circe*** `0.9.3` _(the code may change)_ or upgrade to **Circe** `0.11.1` and **Scala** `2.12.8` _(which were the ones I used)_.

Answer (score 0):

```
val path = "some/path/to/jsonFile.json"
spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code if your json file not very big

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("some/path/to/jsonFile.json").values)
```